# How to split a String and a Floating point figure vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a POS system where every click adds an item name (string) & an item value (float) as 1 item separated to a listbox in Visual Studio. Currently this piece of code works but only with Integers. How do I allow this to work with Floating points?

Error Message:
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

ListBox1.Items.Add("Orange2 - 3.50")

```
    sum = ListBox1.Items.OfType(Of String)().[Select](Function(s) Convert.ToInt32(s.Split(New String() {"-"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1))).Sum()
```

Comment: Maybe use `Convert.ToSingle()`? Supposing that the current culture decimal separator is a dot and not a comma. See [Single.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse) in case you need an `IFormatProvider` (`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`). Also, `Trim()` the string. Safer.

Comment: You need to use the Decimal type instead of a Single or Double, otherwise the pennies will not add up as you want them to. [Convert.ToDecimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_String_).

Comment: If you split on "-" rather than " - ", you may need to use `.Trim()` to remove the leading space.

Comment: Thanks guys, Convert.ToDecimal sorted it!